# SQL-How to UPDATE XML Date column using Modify

Tags: sql, xml

Hi I am very new to xml and I have to update a date (add 15 days to each date) column in a xml file in sql server(how do i add eg. 15 days to the DateAdded dates column(it doesn't seem to work with dateadd). Sample code below:

```
<Product> 
    <ProductDescription ProductID="1" DateAdded="2013-01-01T09:30:10Z"> 
    </ProductDescription>
    <ProductDescription ProductID="1" DateAdded="2013-02-01T09:30:10Z"> 
    </ProductDescription> 
    <ProductDescription ProductID="1"  DateAdded="2013-01-05T09:30:10Z">
    </ProductDescription> 
    <ProductDescription ProductID="1" DateAdded="2013-01-27T09:30:10Z">
    </ProductDescription>
</Product>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of XML DML commands (ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190675(v=sql.90).aspx) that can do simple insert, delete and replace on nodes in the xml, but it's nowhere near as expressive as T-SQL. It's cumbersome for multiple nodes and doesn't support DATEADD.

I think you may have to shred the XML into a temporary table, do the DATEADD and then re-assemble it.